# Calling Method Wrapped for JS on v8 ObjectWrap from C++

Tags: node.js, v8

I'm using a node module and would like to call some of its methods on subclasses of ObjectWrap from C++. It's not entirely clear to me how to correctly construct the Arguments object in the function definitions.

For instance, I'd like to call the following method (Context2d extends ObjectWrap):

```
Handle<Value>
Context2d::LineTo(const Arguments &args) {
    HandleScope scope;

    if (!args[0]->IsNumber()) 
        return ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(String::New("lineTo() x must be a number")));
    if (!args[1]->IsNumber()) 
        return ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(String::New("lineTo() y must be a number")));

    Context2d *context = ObjectWrap::Unwrap<Context2d>(args.This());
    cairo_line_to(context->context(), args[0]->NumberValue(), args[1]->NumberValue()); 

    return Undefined();
}
```

So, concisely: having an unwrapped Context2D, how do I call the static LineTo such that the same instance is returned from the args.This call? I realize of course that I can figure this out by digging through v8, but I was hoping someone knowledgable on the topic could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call it with something like this. I'm assuming that the function is `toLine` on the object. You haven't shown your object prototype construction so you'll have to adjust this to match.

```
int x = 10;
int y = 20;
Context2D *context = ...;

// Get a reference to the function from the object.
Local<Value> toLineVal = context->handle_->Get(String::NewSymbol("toLine"));
if (!toLineVal->IsFunction()) return; // Error, toLine was replaced somehow.

// Cast the generic reference to a function.
Local<Function> toLine = Local<Function>::Cast(toLineVal);

// Call the function with two integer arguments.
Local<Value> args[2] = {
  Integer::New(x),
  Integer::New(y)
};
toLine->Call(context->handle_, 2, args);
```

This should be equivalent to this JS:

```
var toLineVal = context.toLine;
if (typeof toLineVal !== 'function') return; // Error

toLineVal(10, 20);
```